# Modelling dynamic panel data

Tags: regression, panel-data, dynamic-regression

I have a question about a dynamic panel data model. Consider the panel data model: $y_{it} = \alpha_i + x'_{it}\beta + \delta y_{i,t-1} + \epsilon_{it}$. This cannot be estimated because $\alpha_i$ is correlated with the explanatory variable $y_{i,t-1}$ yielding inconsistent parameter estimates when $T$ is finite. There are many different ways for consistently estimating the parameters. One way I found on a forum is to model:

$y_{i,t}=μ_{it}+δ(y_{i,t−1}−μ_{i,t-1})+ϵ_{i,t}, ϵ_{i,t}∼Normal(0,1)$, where $\mu_{it} = \alpha_{i} + x'_{it}\beta$.

However, I do not really know why this model solves the problem of correlation between the $\alpha_i$ and the lagged value $y_{i,t-1}$, since working out the brackets only gives me: $y_{it} = (1-\delta)\alpha_{i} + (1-\delta)x'_{it}\beta + \delta y_{i,t-1} + \epsilon_{it}$.

Can someone explain this to me, or knows a reference where it is explained? I am really stuck with this and cannot find a paper where this is used.

Comment: There's no $y_{i,t-1}$ on the right side of that equation.

Comment: Could you maybe elaborate a bit more on your statement? Is it because in this case you model $(1-\delta)y_{it} = (1-\delta)\alpha_{i} + (1-\delta)(x'_{it}-x'_{i,t-1})\beta +\varepsilon_{it}$

Comment: Look at your first equation.

Comment: @TheLaconic I updated my question, now it is correct!

Comment: On which forum did you find this? It may be worth googing Arellano Bond for a solution

Comment: @ChristophHanck This is the link to the forum: https://discourse.mc-stan.org/t/dynamic-panel-data-models-with-stan/5136/18. It is dynamic panel models in bayesian analysis